# Getting specific values from Web3js getPastEvents

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, smartcontracts, web3js

I would like to know how to pull the account value from returnValues: Result {} of this web3.eth.Contract

This code logs to the console just fine, but I have scoured documentation on objects and on web3js to find ways to transform this object to no avail. I have also tried filtering and topics
per https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#id48 but have had no luck...

[image]

```
for (const element2 of lendingPairList) {
                  const eventPair = new web3.eth.Contract(PairContractABI, element2)
                        eventPair.getPastEvents("Deposit", {                          
                          fromBlock: 12867493,
                          toBlock: 'latest'
                      })
                      .then(events => console.log(events))
              .catch((err) => console.error(err));
                    }
                  }}      
                )}
              }
            )
          })
        }}
```

Comment: Likely your loaded ABI does not match the deployed contract, so it cannot match events to their human readable ABI. Please edit the question and add more context information if you believe this is the case.

Comment: The ABI is an exact match to the confirmed contract code ABI on etherscan.